# Why is setting a static IP on my Ubuntu Hyper-V guest making it inaccessible from my host

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine running on Windows 10 Hyper-V host.  I'm trying to configure my virtual machine so that it keeps a static IP address (say 192.168.1.105) from which the virtual machine is accessible from the host.  I also want my virtual machine to be able to access the Internet while using a static IP if possible.

My first problem is that I've been trying to follow instructions that I've seen about configuring my virtual machine with a static IP, but that makes my virtual machine inaccessible from my host.

My second problem is that I haven't found any instructions that show how to configure a static IP while allowing my virtual machine to still access the Internet.

When I run `ifconfig` on my virtual machine (before making any changes to try to configure a static IP), this is what I get

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.111.24  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 192.168.111.31
        inet6 fe80::ce8c:bd18:4133:8f25  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:20:6d:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 155361  bytes 72805251 (72.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59291  bytes 11119691 (11.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4483342  bytes 2934973527 (2.9 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4483342  bytes 2934973527 (2.9 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I've tried putting this in /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:    
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.105/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4]
```

Then I run `sudo netplan apply`.  Now my virtual machine has the IP 192.168.1.105, but it can't access the Internet and my host can't ping it.

My primary question is how do I configure the static IP on my virtual machine so that my host can access it on that IP?

My second question (if this is possible) is how do I get Internet access on my virtual machine once I configure a static IP?